# Can you convert the output of a EXEC sp_executesql into view or table

Tags: t-sql, view, sp-executesql

The SQL below does exactly as expected, turns a fields which contains multiple tests all separated by a coma, groups then by Id and turns the  Tests into Column headings and return a 1 or 0 depending if the person (Id) had that test recorded in the field mentioned.

Ideally I'd have this as a view but as it's data driven there is a chance it changes over time (new tests that are performed etc).

```
DECLARE
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@y    AS INT,
@sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
-- Construct the column list for the IN clause
SET @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(TestsPeformed.value) AS y FROM badger.[Mother_DIGN_BloodTestsAndResults]
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(TestsPeformed, ',') as TestsPeformed
        GROUP BY TestsPeformed.value
            ) AS Y
ORDER BY y
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');

-- Construct the full T-SQL statement
-- and execute dynamically
SET @sql = N'
select * into #tbl 
from ( SELECT EntityID, UPPER(TestsPeformed.value) as Test
        FROM badger.[Mother_DIGN_BloodTestsAndResults]
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(TestsPeformed, '','') as TestsPeformed
        GROUP BY EntityID, TestsPeformed.value
    ) t(EntityID, s);

select *
from #tbl
PIVOT (
  COUNT(s)
  FOR s IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO
```

[image: Shows output of sp-execute_sp]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no. You can't do a dynamic PIVOT without using dynamic SQL, and I don't think you can't use dynamic SQL in a view.  How often do the tests change? If infrequently, an alternative is to periodically use dynamic SQL to refresh a view definition. Your end application could then access that view. Perhaps your view could select for all defined tests, whether present or not in the results. Your application could then scan the results and remove unneeded columns. One last idea is to just return raw data and let your application build the tabular arrangement.

Comment: In the same way you dynamically build your query you could dynamically build a `create table` statement as either a global temp table or a user table in tempdb, for example, then insert into it from your dynamic pivot query.

Comment: Sure, but once you create the view or table neither of those will be dynamic. i.e. you can take the generated sql and create a view with it, you could even include `create view as` etc. into the generated sql so the view gets re-created when you run the stored proc.  The table is a bit the same, you would need to truncate  the table before doing a select into. So, yes there are ways to do what you ask - but it doesn't remove the need for dynamic sql.